# Octave/Matlab: min of two vectors

Tags: matlab, octave, min

Let's take two vectors:

```
a = [1 ; 2; 3]
b = [0 ; 9 ; -5]
```

If I want minimum value of the vector and it's position I can simply:

```
[x, ix] = min(a)
```

I can also compare two vectors and get minimum values:

```
> min(a, b)
ans =

   0
   2
  -5
```

But it is impossible to get positions of min values of two vectors:

```
> [x, ix] = min(a, b)
x =

   0
   2
  -5

error: element number 2 undefined in return list
```

Why? How to get them? Is there a simple method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's how to do that:

```
[v id]=min([a,b]')
```

Comment: Note that that also transposes the minima/indices, so `v` and `id` are row vectors while `a` and `b` were column vectors. Often doesn't matter, but often it does.

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of having the right insight:

```
[x,ix] = min([a b],[],2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must think about what the intended output of ix is.

This shows you in which vector the minimum is:

```
ix=a<b;
x=a.*ix+b.*not(ix);
```